# App crashing on older Android versions (ExpandableListView custom drawable)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, expandablelistview

I have an app with ExpandableListView and every header has it's own drawable as background. Here's the code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);
    {
        switch(groupPosition){
        case 0:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
            break;
        case 1:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drugi_letniki_color));
            break;
        case 2:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
            break;
        case 3:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cetrti_letniki_color));
            break;
        }
    }
```

This works completely fine on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 but when I try it on emulator with Android version 2.2 it crashes.

This is the logcat file:

```
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setBackground
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.whizzapps.stpsurniki.ExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:100)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:445)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1238)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1044)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-05 20:46:45.914: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is line 100:

```
convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
```

As you can see I already tried solving the problem by disabling the custom background on older versions but it seems like it ignores the if statement.

**EDIT: If anyone is still wondering how exactly I solved the problem; here's the code:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    {
        switch(groupPosition){
        case 0:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
            break;
        case 1:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drugi_letniki_color));
            break;
        case 2:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
            break;
        case 3:
            convertView.setBackground(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cetrti_letniki_color));
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
    {
        switch(groupPosition){
        case 0:
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
            break;
        case 1:
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drugi_letniki_color));
            break;
        case 2:
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.light_blue));
            break;
        case 3:
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cetrti_letniki_color));
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is because .setBackgroundDrawable is available on API 1 and up, while .setBackground is only available on API 16 and up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check may not work because `Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` is not defined in 2.2.

You'll just have to use a constant if you want to do the check.

**Edit**

Also, you have a semi-colon after your `if` statement. You should remove that so your condition will actually control whether or not you go into your `if` statement's code block.

Comment: I tried inserting direct version code but it still executes the if statement. I tried if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8);

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colon.

Comment: It should just be `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8)` no semi-colon after the condition.

Comment: Ohhh I can't believe I did that. I completely missed the fact that I accidently put ; after the if statement. English isn't my native language so I didn't know what you mean by "semi-colon" at first. Thank you very much!